# If Data Allready Exists In A Cell Overwrite It With New Data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, data-transfer, cells

I have an excel sheet with IDs beside cases. When I work the case and get a reply I want the excel spreadsheet to work out its the same case and update the original without adding a new case onto the sheet.

I have attached a screenshot to show a really rough example, A reply has come in for ID 2 and 3 as ID 4 and 5 but I would link the reply to replace the data in ID 2 and 3 and erase the data in the Reply field (keep the data in the other fields).

Unsure how to do this. I know what I want to do but still learning excel stuff so any recommendations would be helpful.

[image]
[Link To Image](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOHp-kEdFAeVCzE5HtHj6nfxgODokt2ZhKKH0r62Z-jY4rX0UQ1eKocBa8zsgIEog?key=TnBQT1E2M09pY1V2V2RPVlVSRk5BanN6Nzl2eC1n)

Comment: Thanks for the update Adam. No one seems to be able to help me with this query V_V

Comment: This can be done with VBA (Macros).

Comment: You need something to determine it is the same case.  Usually this is a unique identifier for the case.  Using the subject isn't really a good solution since there could be duplicates.  You also haven't specified how the data comes in and what you have tried.  Also since we don't know the format of the data coming in, any code people could write would be very generic and likely would need lots of tweaking before it worked for your specific case.